# Setting Promise object to img [src] sets image to null..sometimes

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I use Angular within my Electron app. I have a component with an array of objects called `files`, where each `file` has a member called `preview` which is a **Promise** object and returns a `file://` object.

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let file of files;">
<img mat-list-avatar [src]="file.preview ? (file.preview | async | safe) : 'assets/file.png'"
...
```

```
  async getPreview() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // simplified for example
      resolve("assets/file.png");
    });
  }
  ...
  for (let file in files) {
    file.preview = getPreview();
  }
```

`files` is an **@Input** in this component. When I rebuild this array in the parent component I often get broken images. (see screenshot below).

Eventually, by moving the mouse across the window, the images are drawn properly. Does anyone know if there is a redraw missing somewhere, or how I can find out why the img src is temporarily set to null sometimes?

P.S. In the `safe` pipe I can confirm that the incoming value is already null in some cases, although `file.preview` has a Promise object attached to it.

Thank you!

**After refocusing the app window:**

[image]

**After moving the mouse for a second across the app window:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below code

```
for (let file in files) { 
file.preview = getPreview();
} 

this.files=[...this.files]:
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately that doesn't help. What I realized is that `file.preview ? (file.preview | async | safe) : 'assets/file.png'` returns `null` on the first call in `safe`. It just tunnels the url through, but a good use for breakpoints. How can this return null? The Promise object doesn't have any `reject(..)` call

Comment: Is it working now? It will work without the safe pipe, right?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's still the same. `safe` just tunnels the url through where I can see what the input is, which is `null` in some cases

Comment: I couldn't make it reproducible on Stackblitz. It might be related to Electron. I will try one more thing, otherwise make a minmal example on Github

Comment: I think I just got it! Instead of `ipcRenderer.on("focus"` to recreate the `files` array, I now use `@HostListener('window:focus'` and that works :-o